# Handling bad layers and empty layers using QGIS

Tags: qgis, osx

I'm a novice in GIS.

I'm using QGIS 2.0.1. (Dufour) with Mac OS X (10.6.8). I have couple of dozens(?) of vector layers added on a project. At some point, when I opened a project, application opened a window "*Handle bad layers*". As far as I know, this should pop up when the project cannot find the file due to its new location, for example. There were a few (ca. 5) layers listed. But in the columns "*New file*" and "*New datasource*" there were the same path and file name. When I tried to select a file from the list and relocate it, QGIS crashed. After that it crashes every time at the same point. If I close the window, it's possible to get ahead. QGIS removed those files (vector layers) from the project's "*Layers*" list. That's not too bad. But now all the other layers in the project are empty.

- If I right-click one of them in the "*Layers*" list and choose "*Show feature count*", it shows the right number, for example [13176]. But the style definitions under it (I've made the categorized color style according to one attribute value of the data), it shows [0] as feature count value.
- if I choose "Open attribute table", it's empty. When I checked size of the original file (added as vector layer), it has some data.

I have NOT changed the location of data files - some earlier QGIS backup project files still find them. 
Am I having too many layers, perhaps?

Comment: What data sources do these layers come from? CSV, GPX and some others might react strange on re-opening.

Comment: They are open data of National Land Survey of Finland. I've downloaded them as .mif (MapInfo).